# What is your favorite bittering hop.

Tags: hops, bittering

What is your favorite bittering hop.  Ours is Galena

Comment: My fav is Perle.

Not to be a dick, but this is a little too open-ended of a question for this forum.

Comment: Downvoted for being too vague and not particularly useful question.  I suggest others downvote as well, no offense to Tim, but just to get this old question off the unanswered list.

Comment: Best way to get it off unanswered is to have an admin delete it, or upvote any of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Chinook (15chars)

Answer (score 0):

I love Simcoe.  But I love IPAs.

Answer (score 0):

Nugget and Magnum

Answer (score 0):

Simcoe and Columbus
mark
www.backyardbrewer.blogspot.com
www.thebackyardbrewer.com